# iOS : assign a class to inner view using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have one `viewController` and assigned a viewcontroller class in storyboard. I drag drop another UIView on the existing view controller. How to assign a different objective C or `UIViewController` class to that inner `UIView`?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your question is ,

you can assign new view to your viewController using

```
viewController.view=innerView
```

or if you want to add another viewController to current view you can use (**Implementing UIViewController Contentment**)

```
[self addChildViewController:newVC];
[newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
newVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,160,504);
[self.view addSubview:newVC.view];
```